# Subject no longer authenticated in session after logging in with Shiro

Tags: java, jersey, guice, shiro

I am using Guice + Jersey + Shiro to login via a REST API and then use the same HTTP session under which I logged in to and have my permissions work for that resource.

Below is my code.

Firstly, my servlet configuration:-

```
public class ServletConfiguration extends GuiceServletContextListener
{
    private ServletContext mServletContext;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent inEvent)
    {
        mServletContext = inEvent.getServletContext();

        super.contextInitialized(inEvent);
    }

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector()
    {
        mServletContext.addListener(new au.com.tt.agora.configuration.CbiCleanupHttpSessionListener());

        return Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets()
            {
                install(new TTShiroWebModule(mServletContext));
                install(new ShiroAopModule());

                filter("/*").through(GuiceShiroFilter.class);

                bind(ShiroLoginResource.class);
                bind(ShiroResource.class);

                filter("/*").through(GuiceContainer.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now, this is my test realm:-

package au.com.tt.agora.configuration.shiro;

```
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationToken;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.SimpleAuthenticationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.AuthorizationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.SimpleAuthorizationInfo;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.PrincipalCollection;

public class TestRealm extends AuthorizingRealm
{

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken inToken) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        UsernamePasswordToken upToken = (UsernamePasswordToken) inToken;

        if (upToken.getUsername().equals("Kamal") || upToken.getUsername().equals("NotKamal"))
            return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(upToken.getUsername(), upToken.getPassword(), getName());

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection inPrincipals)
    {
        String username = (String) inPrincipals.fromRealm(getName()).iterator().next();
        SimpleAuthorizationInfo authzInfo = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
        if (username.equals("Kamal"))
        {
            authzInfo.addStringPermission("PRODMA:READ:AU");
            authzInfo.addStringPermission("PRODMA:WRITE:KB");
            authzInfo.addStringPermission("SUPPMA:READ:KB");
        }
        else
        {
            authzInfo.addStringPermission("PRODMA:READ:AU");
            authzInfo.addStringPermission("PRODMA:WRITE:KB");
        }

        return authzInfo;
    }
}
```

This is the web module

```
package au.com.tt.agora.configuration.shiro;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.apache.shiro.guice.web.ShiroWebModule;

public class TTShiroWebModule extends ShiroWebModule
{

    public TTShiroWebModule(ServletContext inServletContext)
    {
        super(inServletContext);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void configureShiroWeb()
    {
        bindRealm().to(TestRealm.class);
        addFilterChain("**/shiroResource/*", ANON);
    }

}
```

Here is the resource I use to login:-

```
package au.com.tt.agora.configuration.jaxrs.resources;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationToken;
import org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;

import com.google.inject.Inject;

import au.com.tt.agora.configuration.option.ClientProvider;
import au.com.tt.agora.configuration.option.ConfigurationProvider;
import au.com.tt.agora.login.web.request.LoginRequest;
import au.com.tt.agora.login.web.request.LoginResponse;
import au.com.tt.agora.login.web.service.LoginHandler;
import au.com.tt.calypso.cbi.CalypsoException;

@Path("/{client}/shiroLogin")
public class ShiroLoginResource
{
    private static final String ROUTING_TOKEN_HEADER = "proxy-jroute";

    @POST
    @Path("/standard")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String login(@Context HttpServletRequest inServletRequest) throws CalypsoException
    {
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        subject.login(new UsernamePasswordToken("Kamal", "Password", false));
        return getSessionIdWithRouting(inServletRequest);
    }

    private String getSessionIdWithRouting(HttpServletRequest inRequest)
    {
        String sessionId = inRequest.getSession().getId();

        return(sessionId);
    }
}
```

And here is the resource I am calling:-

```
package au.com.tt.agora.configuration.jaxrs.resources;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils;
import org.apache.shiro.authz.annotation.RequiresPermissions;
import org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.google.inject.Inject;

@Path("/{client}/shiroResource")
public class ShiroResource
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShiroResource.class);

    @Inject
    public ShiroResource()
    {
    }

    @POST
    @Path("requiresProdma.do")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @RequiresPermissions({ "PRODMA:*:*" })
    public String prodmaRequired()
    {
        return "Success";
    }

    @POST
    @Path("requiresSuppma.do")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @RequiresPermissions({ "SUPPMA:*:*" })
    public String suppmaRequired()
    {
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        subject.getPrincipal();
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

If I put a breakpoint into suppmaRequired and call this resource, I can see that subject is not authenticated.

My understanding on how Shiro works is obviously faulty, but I don't know what I am not doing.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Not sure if it makes a difference, but I am using URL rewriting to access the web session.

Basically, I am using the fetch API to test this. Here is an example:-

```
fetch("http://localhost/app/tt/shiroLogin/standard", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  } ,
  body: '{"username":"myName","password":"myPassword"}'
})
.then(function(res) {
  return res.text();
})
.then(function(sessionId) {
  return fetch("http://localhost/app/tt/shiroResource/requiresSuppma.do;JSESSIONID=" + sessionId,
              {
                method: "POST"
              });  
})
.then(function(res) {
    return res.text();
})
.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

I am also deploying to glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was not a Shiro problem in the end. I was using two different sessions going from the ShiroLoginResource to ShiroResource.

I forgot that you actually needed to inject with a session level object in Guice to force Guice to create a session.  Stupid me.

Once I injected a session scoped dependency into ShiroLoginResource and interacted with it, then everything just worked.

I will keep this question open because it gives some useful code snippets.